# Magento2.4 rying to import simple products via csv

Tags: product-import

I am trying to import products via a csv in Magento2.4 the file is a bit big its 189MB in size.
I edited the php.ini file to allow a bigger max_imput_size and upload_max_filesize . I restarted apache but now when I upload the file I get a spinner in the browser that just never goes away.
I am not sure what else I could do to get this not to be stuck?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing products using csv in slots
For example :- 500 skus single time in single csv , then 500 more
This is how , you can import it into magento.

Answer (score 0):

189MB!! how many products do you have in there?! I would split that CSV down into manageable chunks using cmd line.

I did a 64MB file last night and it worked very well. Maybe split yours into 3.

AWK is a good command line tool for splitting CSV if Excel is struggling.

You could also try Import/Export by Firebear. This handles very large files.

MagManager will also handle this kind of loads as it works on a local DB and uploads after the import has happened.

Comment: Thank's it is a few thousand products which I am trying to import. I will break it into 3 import files and see if that does it.

Comment: Now I am getting an error that says Invalid value in Store column (store doesn't exist?) yet I am putting the value of code from the Store View column in the Magento admin panel into the store_view_code column in the excel sheet?

Comment: sorry i missed your response. what are you putting as the code _base or something similar?